# Django - how to run methods by dropdown select on submit form?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

Is in Django forms, possible to run specific methods by selecting dropdownmenu, or radioselect?
for example, on form submit when i select Input option, then run `foo` method and when i select Outout, run `bar` or so...

```
STATUS = (
    ("in", _("Input")),
    ("out", _("Output")),
)
class MaterialFlow(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices = STATUS)
```

Comment: With or without submitting the form?

Comment: @percent20 with submit form

Comment: When and where do you want run this metod ? After form validation, in your view ? In your models ?

Comment: @Wilfried in views or after validation

Comment: You need to check in after validation of your form, the status value. In `form.instance.status`. And with this result, you can run the method you want. Do you have right your view ? Can you show us this code ?

Comment: @Wilfried My problem is I have no idea how to do it. I could not even sample code to write.

Comment: You can follow the good tutorial of Django : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/

Because your problem here is not about run methods, but more about how django works. :) Kepp going !! ;)